# C# Unhandled Exception (with no message) using Docker windowsservercore

Tags: c#, docker, msbuild, windows-server

microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.6.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016`image to run a`.Net Framework 4.6.1`project that was built with`MSbuild`, it runs fine running it stand alone in a windows machine but when it comes to docker it doesn't work and the only exception I got is an empty message

```
PS C:\app> .\MyProject.Rest.exe

Unhandled Exception:
```

I have the following version of .Net Framework installed on the container

```
PS C:\app> (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full").Version
4.8.03761
PS C:\app> Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion, OsHardwareAbstractionLayer

WindowsProductName             WindowsVersion OsHardwareAbstractionLayer
------------------             -------------- --------------------------
Windows Server 2016 Datacenter                10.0.14393.3297


PS C:\app>
```

The Dockerfile contains the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.6.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell"]

COPY . 'C:\\app\\'
EXPOSE 10003
WORKDIR 'C:\\app\\'

CMD MyProject.Rest.exe
```

And the project was build with the following command:

```
MSBuild.exe '.\Project\Project.sln' /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:RunOctoPack=true /p:OctoPackPackageVersion=$env:appveyor_build_version
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the run environment, we use **Windows Server 2012** and some features are not supported after the update to **Windows Server 2016** everything works fine.